# PDF libraries that work in Windows Store applications

Tags: library, pdf, windows-8

I am using `itext.dll` for creating PDF in Windows 8.1 applications. It's working fine on a local machine. but it's not supported while try to build in Windows Store.

Are there any alternative open source DLL libraries available for create pdf in Windows 8.1 applications which are also supported in Windows Store?

---

[Link to error message in Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8JSK44jZ) (or click on edit to view hidden text)

Comment: I moved the error log to Pastebin and left a link instead since it was cluttering the question. Feel free to roll back the edit if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know none of the open source PDF libraries for .NET work in Windows Store applications. 
A commercial product that supports Windows Store applications is [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-wpf-silverlight-winrt/xfinium-pdf-overview.html).